# How to find out application is logging in which time zone?

Tags: java, logging

I looked into logback.xml file: but couldn't find any clue.

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
         <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: better visual clarity

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a timezone, the default timezone of your JVM is used. Like its the case in your code.

You can set a fix timezone by adding the timezone-parameter like that:

```
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS, YourTimeZone}
```